# Linq repository vs dbcontext bring different result the same query

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-mvc-5

I am about to get freak out with this, I am using repository pattern and unityOfwork and if I use the db.context to bring a list works fine If I use the same query on the repository bring repeated values, here is my code.

This code bring the correct data

```
var myList = (from p in db.Products_Sizes
                         where p.productsID == 181 && p.ColorID == 200 && p.SizeID == 133
                         select new SelectListItem
                         {
                             Value = p.eyepower.ToString(),
                             Text = p.eyepower.ToString()
                         }).OrderBy(p => p.Value).ToList();
```

the correct data is

- 1.00
- 1.50
- 2.00
- 2.50

now if I use this code.

```
var myList = _unitOfWork.ProductsSizes.Find(a => a.productsID == 181 && a.ColorID == 200 && a.SizeID == 133).ToList()
             .Select(u => new SelectListItem
        {
            Value = u.eyepower.ToString(),
            Text = u.eyepower.ToString()
        });
```

result

- 1.00
- 1.00
- 1.00
- 1.00

or any of other repeated

here is the Find `IEnumerable Find(Expression> predicate); in the interface

I know the data is correct bc I ran a query in the sql server and is fine the data

I cant figure out why , any idea?`
here is my whole structure 
base interface

```
public interface IRepositoryBase<T> where T : class 
{IEnumerable<T> Find(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate);}
```

base repository

```
public class RepositoryBase<T> : IRepositoryBase<T> where T : class
```

{protected readonly DbContext Context;

```
public RepositoryBase(DbContext context)
{
    Context = context;
}

public T Get(int id)
{
    return Context.Set<T>().Find(id);
}

public IEnumerable<T> GetAll()
{

    return Context.Set<T>().ToList();
}

public IEnumerable<T> Find(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
{
    return Context.Set<T>().Where(predicate);
}}
```

the productsize repository is like this

```
 public interface IProductsSizesRepository : IRepositoryBase<Products_Sizes>
{

}
```

interface for unityOfWork

```
public interface IUnitOfWork : IDisposable
{
    IOrdersRepository ProductSizes{ get; }}
```

unityOfwork class

```
public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
{
    public readonly EFDbContext _dbContext;

    public UnitOfWork(EFDbContext dbContext)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
        ProductsSizes = new ProductsSizesRepository(_dbContext);
    }
 public IProductsSizesRepository ProductsSizes { get; private set; }}
```

finally the controller where I am having this problem as you can see I am using ninject to inject IUnityOfWork in the controller to have access to the repositories

```
public class SelectProductController : Controller{private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;
public SelectProductController(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
{
    _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
}}
```

Comment: instead of Find, use Where

Comment: already did, same result

Comment: Could it be that `_unitOfWork.ProductsSizes` is not equal to `db.Products_Sizes`?

Comment: Check also resulting SQL using `((System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery)query)
            .ToTraceString();`

Comment: not that 'public IProductsSizesRepository ProductsSizes { get; private set; }' from here

Comment: Can you show your ProductSizes repository?

Comment: going to edit the post with the whole structure in a min

Comment: see original post for the repository and unitiyofwork classes

Answer (score 0):

I ended up placing this in the repository

```
(from p in db.Products_Sizes
                     where p.productsID == 181 && p.ColorID == 200 && p.SizeID == 133
                     select new SelectListItem
                     {
                         Value = p.eyepower.ToString(),
                         Text = p.eyepower.ToString()
                     }).OrderBy(p => p.Value).ToList();
```